# Convert the string into variable and numpy

Tags: python, numpy, oop

```
for i in range(65,67):
    temp = "{}_letter".format(chr(i))
    globals()[temp] = np.genfromtxt("{}.txt".format(chr(i)))
    

print(A_letter)
```

It is my code. The role of this code is to automatically load words from files like A.txt, B.txt... etc.
To varaibles being converted from strings, which is the line above and the variable will look like `A_letter`. The problem is the output of A_letter looks like:
OUTPUT:
`[nan nan nan nan nan nan]`. How to fix it?

Comment: What is the end goal here, seems like a dictionary would be a better option

Comment: Avoid as much as possible using globals and locals explicitly. Use lists to store multiple values

Answer (score 0):

Ok, nevermind... I forgot to put `dtype=str` as a second argument...

But stil if i am gonna to put this code under `__init__(self):` in class. Is it better to use locals or globals variables?